# Recommendation for Sqlite DB manager application?

Tags: sqlite

There are quite a few Sqlite GUI applications listed here:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

some appear to be incomplete, buggy, not maintained, etc. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: If you use an IDE like **IntelliJ IDEA**, **PHPStorm** or **WebStorm** you can open, query, design and edit `.sqlite` databases directly with its own **Database Tool Window**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I use the [SQLite manager plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817).

It seems pretty stable to me.

Comment: It's pretty good. Wish there was a standalone version. It doesn't show guids correctly, plus has some other bugs. Works correctly with foreign keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, the absolutely fantastic "SQLite manager plugin for Firefox" no longer works as a plugin for Firefox since Firefox Quantum (version 56).

Comment: @zax Try [SQLitespeed](http://www.rifin.co.za/software/sqlc/).

Comment: Thanks, @user4157124, but I did transition to SQLiteStudio, which fortunately I've found to be every bit as powerful as SQLite Manager plugin.  Only issue with SQLiteStudio is that for is very slow for data import operations in comparison.

Comment: Try https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: The link cant be found.

Answer (score 18):

Here's another free option.  It has been pretty stable for me.  [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/index.rvt)

Answer (score 12):

For Windows: I've been looking for functionality and a comfortable GUI - it's been particularly hard to satisfy the latter requirement, but these two picks are both fine:

a) **Good enough:**  [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/features.html)

Less expensive, fully featured manager. The author is very responsive to comments and bug reports, and publishes updates frequently. The flip side, if you look at version history, is that new releases seem to introduce new bugs, which are then fixed in sunsequent builds. The GUI is fine, very good for quickly designing new databases; a little less so for designing queries and working with large amounts of data. Main gripe: you can't see the schema while editing a query (without flipping tabs in the program).

b) **Nearly perfect:** [SQLite Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/)

Pricier. Rich UI, easy access to all features, nice visual query builder and automatic SQL formatter for readability, lots of eye candy. There is a separate, more specialized query builder (SQLite Code Factory), but you can make do with just the main Maestro application. Main gripe: can't seem to be able to change font size for table display and the default is a little too small; at the beginning it's easy to get lost in the thicket of tabs, though overall I find the GUI very productive.

Both solutions are very stable in my experience, and both seem to offer occasional discounts, if you can afford to wait.

For just browsing data, try [SQLite Spy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/) - free and lets you execture queries, but no or little GUI support for editing. Very convenient for quick lookups though.

Comment: Since you wrote this three years ago, I'll just confirm for new readers that SQLite Maestro still does not let you change the font size in table editors and the overall UI. For my eyes, it is tolerable on a low-density display (<100dpi) but very hard to read on my ThinkPad's 147dpi display. They do have a font size setting but it only affects code/text editors, not the table editor and UI. A real shame since it's such a nice product otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

Spent the morning looking for a good Sqlite Database Manager/Browser and have settled on [SqliteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/), currently v2.20.28, which I'm running on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

- The download is one 4.3MB uncompressed executable file. Period!
- It's fast, well-behaved, and uses modest resources.
- The interface is clean and attractive with logical functionality.
- I don't say this often, but it's just a "A Joy to Use".
- It was developed and is actively maintained by Pawel Salawa who is is to be commended for producing a very nice program.

I just used it to merge two Firefox FloatNotes databases (Sqlite v3), which just use a single table...

- The target database is on the local host where SqliteStudio is running (i.e. /0/LX02)
- The source database file is on a remote host mounted via SSHFS to /0/LX04
- Opened the two database files using Add Database.
- Used the SQL Editor to execute an INSERT to the LX02 database from a SELECT on the LX04.
- Click the Commit icon when all goes well or Rollback if there are errors to fix.
- Refresh the table data to see the inserted rows.

There's no Import GUI functionality but merging is pretty simple if you know SQL. I supplied NULL for the first column which is the unique-id primary-key so that Sqlite would autoincrement, thus renumbering the rows being merged in...

```
INSERT INTO [floatnotes.sqlite].floatnotes
SELECT NULL,
       url,
       protocol,
       content,
       x,
       y,
       w,
       h,
       color,
       status,
       guid,
       creation_date,
       modification_date
  FROM [floatnotes-LX04.sqlite].floatnotes;
```

Comment: It's evidently changed a bit since 2012: The download is now 33 MB (Windows). A large part of that is the Qt framework.

Answer (score 5):

[I like SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)

Comment: Alright, but Kinda buggy, and as said by P a u l, It's out of data. Still useable though.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [SQLite Professional](http://www.sqlitepro.com) and it's been reliable.  The only downside was that changes I made to the db via the iOS simulator didn't resolve in the app (I had to close it and reopen for changes to show) but that feature was added in a recent version. So now it does everything I need. I'm happy with the support. It's good for testing and I use it to build out the db structure.  Never been buggy.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Sqliteman](http://www.sqliteman.com) in the past. Quite nice.

Comment: sqliteman.com is dead in 2019

Answer (score 3):

[SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) is a good choice

Comment: Tiny download and appears polished. Non-commercial use only though.

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite.org has a list of management tools available here:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

Comment: From the link itself: "This information is obsolete."

Comment: And now the link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If your using OSX you may like [SQLPro for SQLite](https://sqlitepro.com) ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlite-professional/id586001240?ls=1&mt=12)).

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Versions Integration (rollback to previous versions).
- Inline data filtering.
- Exporting options to CSV, JSON, XML and MySQL.
- Column reordering.
- Full screen support.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [SQL Explorer](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/). The firefox plugin is awesome, but it couldn't handle BIGINTs properly (it truncated them). I have noticed that the .jar driver doesn't seem to support FTS4 (but it does support FTS3) and doesn't show indexes in the data structure.

I like SQL explorer as you can use other providers like mySQL too with the one client.

Comment: I think the link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention a platform, so here's a [great comparison](http://www.tandb.com.au/sqlite/compare/?mlp) of Mac OS X SQLite tools. I personally found [MesaSQLite](http://www.mesamysql.com/?realmesa_home) to be most like my preference for database tools, which was CocoaMySQL incidentally. (For Windows, I just used the Firefox add-on mentioned above.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're within Visual Studio most of the time then [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) is good, and as a plus handles encrypted databases.

Answer (score 0):

[Navicat SQLite](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_overview.html) is very good and they support Windows, OS X and Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check MYZSQLExplorer, [here](https://github.com/meizy/MYZSQLExplorer).

Unlike the other tools, it is running on iOS devices (or in the simulator). It is a Viewer, not a management tool, and is not as feature-complete as some of the other tools, but is convenient as you can launch it from within your code and browse your databse from within your app.

Or you can "Open In..." it sqlite stores, by sending them as email attachments.

I developed it in order to help myself during the development and testing phases, and it did help.

If you have any feedback on it, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just CRUD operations on the sqlite database file, then [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is a very option as it has an auto complete feature which drastically improve the speed and efficiency of typing the sql queries.

To use the SQLite database in SQuirreL first download the JDBC driver of the SQLite from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.2/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar) then drop the jar in the lib folder of the SQuirreL folder. Now open SQuirreL and choose Create a New Driver.
In the Example URL field put

> jdbc:sqlite:$file_url

and in Class Name put

> org.sqlite.JDBC

After that choose Create a New Alias and choose the driver that you just added and replace $file_url with the actual location of the sqlite file then click ok and you are done.