# SQLite managers for Windows

Tags: sqlite

What SQLite GUI tools are available for Windows to edit/manage SQLite databases?

The goals are:

- free
- user-friendly
- easy to work with SQLite databases for `create`, `delete`, filling tables with data
- import (xls, csv, mdb, ...) and export

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendation for Sqlite DB manager application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505220/recommendation-for-sqlite-db-manager-application)

Comment: If mdb import is a high priority I suggest you post a separate question for that (good luck.)

Comment: Whatever application you choose, remember that you are working with a file. This means you usually have to save changes to file before they are applied, unlike ordinary SQL-systems.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried already tools mentioned here, and then came across Valentina Studio http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview, which i think is far superior to others GUI tools. It is FREE. It works on three OS: MAC, WIN, LIN. It works as with mySQL/mariaDB, so with PostgreSQL, SQLite and Valentina DB. I think it deserves to be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like the sqlite manager firefox plugin (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). However, I have to say sqlite really lends itself to command line work very well if you are prepared to get over the "no gui" hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of tools
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools
I have tried many of them and finally I choose

SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager

This is also good alternative
SQLite Manager - Add-on for Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I do use the Navicat Database Admin Tools because it works well on Mac OS as well as on Windows, supports different DB servers, and in general well stable. Moreover, you can get absolutely free community edition build - although it  has some limitations, in general it covers basic needs.

More information you will find here http://www.navicat.com/