# Programs for creating, design and administrate(GUI) SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Which programs do you know for subj purpose? Quickie googling reveal 2 progs:

1. [sqlite-manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/)(Firefox extension) 
   Not all features are realizable through GUI, but really easy for use and opensource.
2. [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) 
   Screenshots looks pretty but for Win only.

Please tell me your opinion about program not just link. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendation for Sqlite DB manager application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505220/recommendation-for-sqlite-db-manager-application)

Comment: ye i already understand this=) but i cant delete post and flag it for delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools) table, and may be this information help someone.

And this question are repeat [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505220/recommendation-for-sqlite-db-manager-application?rq=1). Just in time heh.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm using [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/). It is not free, it costs money, but it is a very nice tool when working with multiple database systems, including Sqlite. It has many nice features, such as working with multiple db's from one window, import/export/synchronize data and schemas across different databases etc.

There is also Navicat for SQLite only which costs less I think.

Comment: "sqlite Non-Commercial" license on linux cost less than win =D

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SQLitespy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index). I found it very useful. Its GUI makes it very easy to explore, analyze, and manipulate SQLite3 databases.