# replacing an existing sqlite database in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite

i would like to replace an existing SQLite database in an existing Android application, by another one to use it for a different purpose.

For being clear:

I have the source code of an application who displays an encyclopedia in french (grouped by major themes(humans, animals..) every theme contains books (book one: human activities book 2...) every book contains chapters, and every chapter contains definitions..

My goal is to modify this application (just because i love its structure and general aspect!!) and use it to display an existing phone book grouped by regions, every region contains groups, every group contains clubs and every club have contacts (name, address and one phone number for every contact).

In the app. the database is putted in a raw file (res/raw/...) how can i know the structure of this database to make my phone book structure looks like it.

P.S: this isn't plajiurism...  and also I would like to say sorry: I am a newbie in both of English language an Android programming :-)

Comment: thx Rafi i will check it right now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i know the structure of this database to make my phone book

There are some Sqlite database editors available freely. Assuming that your database is a Sqlite one, if you open the database using one of those editors, you can see the database schema as well as contents of the database. You can also edit the contents if you wish.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505220/recommendation-for-sqlite-db-manager-application).

If you don't know how to use an existing database in your app, you can refer to this [tutorial](http://blog.softeq.com/2012/12/using-pre-populated-sqlite-database-in.html).